# Polynomial with Specific roots

Tags: polynomial-math

Is there a way to find a polynomial having specific roots i.e., 17, 29, 33 etc. The polynomial should satisfy for all these values.
Is there any programming library available to achieve this.

Comment: (x-17)*(x-29)*(x-33) would have the roots you mention. Do you need the coefficients of the polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(x-17)*(x-29)*(x-33) would have the roots you mention. If you need the polynomial for evaluating it at certain points, this form should be enough. If you need all of its coefficients, your best bet is probably using a polynomial library to multiply the binomials.

Comment: except that the coefficients of the polynomial will get 1) large 2) of alternating signs. So please, by all means, keep the polynomial in this form.